# Not Able to call SOAP Webservice with domain name

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using WSDL webservice in my java Portal.To call it I use with IP like 0.0.0.0:0000\MywebServiceWS\example1?wsdl. It working fine 
But when I register it with domain name like,
http://example.mywebservice.com pointing to 0.0.0.0:0000\MywebServiceWS\example1?wsdl.

Now I call http://example.mywebservice.com but it doesn't work for me.

Let me know if any changes needed?

Answer (score 0):

when you only call the link. i think you are only telling it to point to 0.0.0.0:0000. which is not the correct path.

What happens when you call: http://example.mywebservice.com/MywebServiceWS/example1?wsdl

Also try to open the page in your browser. you should be able to open it with
both links

Comment: Yes I have checked with the browser I got the result with static IP, but didn't get the result with domain.